# How does std::flush work?

Tags: c++, stream

Can someone please explain (preferably using plain english) how `std::flush` works?

- What is it?
- When would you flush a stream?
- Why is it important?

Thank you.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Since it wasn't answered *what* `std::flush` happens to be, here is some detail on what it actually is. `std::flush` is a *manipulator*, i.e., a function with a specific signature. To start off simple, you can think of `std::flush` of having the signature

```
std::ostream& std::flush(std::ostream&);
```

The reality is a bit more complex, though (if you are interested, it is explained below as well).

The stream class overload output operators taking operators of this form, i.e., there is a member function taking a manipulator as argument. The output operator calls the manipulator with the object itself:

```
std::ostream& std::ostream::operator<< (std::ostream& (*manip)(std::ostream&)) {
    (*manip)(*this);
    return *this;
}
```

That is, when you "output" `std::flush` with to an `std::ostream`, it just calls the corresponding function, i.e., the following two statements are equivalent:

```
std::cout << std::flush;
std::flush(std::cout);
```

Now, `std::flush()` itself is fairly simple: All it does is to call `std::ostream::flush()`, i.e., you can envision its implementation to look something like this:

```
std::ostream& std::flush(std::ostream& out) {
    out.flush();
    return out;
}
```

The `std::ostream::flush()` function technically calls `std::streambuf::pubsync()` on the stream buffer (if any) which is associated with the stream: The stream buffer is responsible for buffering characters and sending characters to the external destination when the used buffer would overflow or when the internal representation should be synced with the external destination, i.e., when the data is to be flushed. On a sequential stream syncing with the external destination just means that any buffered characters are immediately sent. That is, using `std::flush` causes the stream buffer to flush its output buffer. For example, when data is written to a console flushing causes the characters to appear at this point on the console.

This may raise the question: Why aren't characters immediately written? The simple answer is that writing characters is generally fairly slow. However, the amount of time it takes to write a reasonable amount of characters is essentially identical to writing just one where. The amount of characters depends on many characteristics of the operating system, file systems, etc. but often up to something like 4k characters are written in about the same time as just one character. Thus, buffering characters up before sending them using a buffer depending on the details of the external destination can be a huge performance improvement.

The above should answer two of your three questions. The remaining question is: When would you flush a stream? The answer is: When the characters should be written to the external destination! This may be at the end of writing a file (closing a file implicitly flushes the buffer, though) or immediately before asking for user input (note that `std::cout` is automatically flushed when reading from `std::cin` as `std::cout` is `std::istream::tie()`'d to `std::cin`). Although there may be a few occasions where you explicitly want to flush a stream, I find them to be fairly rare.

Finally, I promised to give a full picture of what `std::flush` actually is: The streams are class templates capable of dealing with different character types (in practice they work with `char` and `wchar_t`; making them work with another characters is quite involved although doable if you are really determined). To be able to use `std::flush` with all instantiations of streams, it happens to be a function template with a signature like this:

```
template <typename cT, typename Traits>
std::basic_ostream<cT, Traits>& std::flush(std::basic_ostream<cT, Traits>&);
```

When using `std::flush` immediately with an instantiation of `std::basic_ostream` it doesn't really matter: The compiler deduces the template arguments automatically. However, in cases where this function isn't mentioned together with something facilitating the template argument deduction, the compiler will fail to deduce the template arguments.

Comment: Fantastic answer. Couldn't find quality info on how flush worked anywhere else.

Answer (score 44):

By default, `std::cout` is buffered, and the actual output is only printed once the buffer is full or some other flushing situation occurs (e.g. a newline in the stream). Sometimes you want to make sure that the printing happens immediately, and you need to flush manually.

For example, suppose you want to report a progress report by printing a single dot:

```
for (;;)
{
    perform_expensive_operation();
    std::cout << '.';
    std::flush(std::cout);
}
```

Without the flushing, you wouldn't see the output for a very long time.

Note that `std::endl` inserts a newline into a stream as well as causing it to flush. Since flushing is mildly expensive, `std::endl` shouldn't be used excessively if the flushing isn't expressly desired.

Comment: Just an additional note for readers: `cout` isn't the only thing that's buffered in C++. `ostream`s in general are typically buffered by default, which also includes `fstream`s and the like.

Comment: Also using `cin` performs the output before it to be flushed, no?

Comment: One thing that baffles me a little is that you said "*By default, std::cout is buffered, and the actual output is only printed once the buffer is full or some other flushing situation occurs*", but why does a single line code like `std::cout<<'.';` print the dot immediately on the console, please?

Answer (score 32):

Here's a short program that you can write to observe what flush is doing

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    cout << "Line 1..." << flush;

    usleep(500000);

    cout << "\nLine 2" << endl;

    cout << "Line 3" << endl ;

    return 0;
}
```

Run this program:  you'll notice that it prints line 1, pauses, then prints line 2 and 3.  Now remove the flush call and run the program again- you'll notice that the program pauses and then prints all 3 lines at the same time.  The first line is buffered before the program pauses, but because the buffer is never flushed, line 1 is not outputted until the endl call from line 2.

Comment: Another way to illustrate this is to `cout << "foo" << flush; std::abort();`.  If you comment out/remove `<< flush`, there's NO OUTPUT!  PS: standard-out-debugging DLLs that call `abort` is a nightmare. DLLs should never call `abort`.

Comment: Tested it myself, for some reason despite the fact I remove the `flush` it still does the same thing: it prints line 1, pauses, then prints line 2 and 3.

Answer (score 8):

A stream is connected to something. In the case of standard output, it could be the console/screen or it could be redirected to a pipe or a file. There is a lot of code between your program and, for example, the hard disk where the file is stored. For example, the operating system is doing stuff with any file or the disk drive itself might be buffering data to be able to write it in fixed size blocks or just to be more efficient.

When you flush the stream, it tells the language libraries, the os and the hardware that you want to any characters that you have output so far to be forced all the way to storage. Theoretically, after a 'flush', you could kick the cord out of the wall and those characters would still be safely stored.

I should mention that the people writing the os drivers or the people designing the disk drive might are free to use 'flush' as a suggestion and they might not really write the characters out. Even when the output is closed, they might wait a while to save them. (Remember that the os does all sorts of things at once and it might be more efficient to wait a second or two to handle your bytes.)

So a flush is a sort of checkpoint.

One more example: If the output is going to the console display, a flush will make sure the characters actually get all the way out to where the user can see them. This is an important thing to do when you are expecting keyboard input. If you think you have written a question to the console and its still stuck in some internal buffer somewhere, the user doesn't know what to type in answer. So, this is a case where the flush is important.

Comment: Your answer makes easy to understand. Thank you!