# In Linux,for loop with blank body executes first. stange behaviour

Tags: c++, time.h

first i used this code:

```
void pause(long n)
{
  clock_t at=clock();
  while(clock()-at<=n)
    ;    
}

int main()
{
  cout<<1;
  pause(100000);
  cout<<2;
}
```

what do u expect?
output will be 1(some time gap)2 right?
NO..!!
its (some time gap)12 how??
Anyways, i changed the pause function as follows-

```
void pause(long n)
{
  for(long i=1; i<=n*n; i++)
    ;
}
```

Still same thing..!!
why this blank for loop executing first??
but if i do this

```
  void pause(long n)
  {
   for(long i=1; i<=n*n; i++)
     cout<<0  ;
  }
```

Now it happily executes output as 10000000000....(many 0s)....00002

Comment: `cout << 1;` doesn't flush the output buffer.  Try adding `cout << std::flush;`. Or `cout.flush()`

Comment: [Cout won't print text without endl inside while loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29315659/995714), [std::cout won't print](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14858262/995714)

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten that cout is buffered stream too. If you want to see 1 and 2 immediately you need to call [flush](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush)

`cout.flush()`

or

`cout << flush;`

Note that `std::endl` also calls flush implicitly