# How can i check user's input while he types it on C++?

Tags: c++, scanf

I am doing some training exercises to get used to C++ on Windows as a new programmer.

Take input from the user of type *String* and form:

```
    (any word) || (any word || <any word || any word> || (any word> etc.
```

Warn the user in real-time, if the:

```
    () or/and <>  Are closed before the input ends.
```

For example, if the user types:

```
    (I am ok
```

I have to warn him at that time that a parenthesis has been opened but hasn't yet been closed.

Since I am a beginner I am a bit lost about how to proceed, I wouldn't prefer a ready solution but rather a way to proceed.

- I use code blocks IDE and GCC compiler.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Linux, Mac, WIndows,... ?

Comment: You do know there are functions to read one character at a time? You might want to [checkout this C input/output reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io). Even if you are only allowed to use [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) you can use that to read a single character at a time as well.

Comment: `std::flush` is actually a C++ function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105650/how-does-stdflush-work. You were looking for [`fflush`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush) (but note that this is for flushing entire lines and not on a per-character base).

Comment: _"...this excersise is by far out of the things that our professor is taughting us all this time..."_. I **strongly doubt** it's true. I'm sure he explained everything you need, what's missing is your brain thinking about the problem but that's the point of homework...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti It really does seem like the teacher is looking for a non-standard solution, in which case the teacher's brain is the one with questionable activity.

Comment: @Lundin I fail to see where anything _non-standard_ is required (but probably just because question is too vague)...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti It is simple: which standard console input function allows interruptions before the user presses enter? Which standard console output function allows you to print elsewhere, other than where the user is currently typing the input?

Comment: @ Adriano Repetti im not raging at teacher , but is true that he hasnt tell as anything about this kind of IO. I think he just wants us to think by our own and to search by our own , thats not bad thing.

Comment: @user2719403 Forcing beginners to run off into the woods looking for non-standard solutions is not a good way of teaching C programming. At any rate, you need to edit the post and specify which compiler you are using and system you are programming for.

Comment: @Lundin one comes to my mind to process input on-the-fly: getchar(). About _write elsewhere_...it's not what question is asking for. User must be _warned_ and he doesn't say how. Yes it may be writing elsewhere (non-standard but what about ncurses? I see you already mentioned it) or printing _elsewhere_. What about stderr? It's allowed and standard. Good or not to teach C using non-standard function... **that's not the point**. If teacher introduced a putsat() function then OP has what he needs to complete his task (I'm not here to judge teacher capabilities from OP question...)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Just like any other standard input function, getchar() will need an EOF (enter press) to return.

Comment: @Lundin getchar() won't wait for \n to return...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti `char ch=getchar(); puts("You pressed enter and learned how getchar works");` Compile & run.

Comment: Try a new post that contains what you have tried.  If the task is daunting -break into smaller programs and work and solve the individual pieces.  Certainly you can post some I/O code.

Comment: @Lunding I'm surprised you talk about _standard_ and you assume stdin (not getchar()!) is line buffered...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First of all this is C++ not C because we don't have something called namespace in C. std is a nampesapce. So we don't have std::flush in C as explained in comments and you won't need it.**

I just tell you what to do ( I wont write the code! ) :

**You haven't told the platform you 're coding on Assuming its windows**

1. You should use a function called `getche()`. It gets a character from user
2. Declare a boolean variable that saves the state of brackets and angular brackets.
3. Put `getche()` function in a loop and as you encountered '(' or '<' set the variable false.
4. If you encountered a closing bracker ( I mean ')' or '>' ) set that variable true.
5. At the end of the application check the variable state. If it was true it means no error was encounterd, otherwise the user had an error.

At last I have put an example for you

Example :

`typedef int boolean; /* Just ignore it. Just know it declares boolean type. */
     boolean brastate, angbrackstate;
     char ch = getche();
     while(ch != EOF) {
         if( ch == '<') {
         angbrackstate = false;
         ... /* Do the remaining yourself as you like challenges!!! */`

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks lot i will try it imidiatelly , Does the char type can hold lot of text? i thought it can hold only a single character

Comment: no it can't you should use arrays

Comment: if u want me to explain it I will do otherwise if you want to google it just search string in C

Comment: I didn't provide any answer for him

Comment: I just gave him the idea

Comment: and an incomplete example

Comment: @Ehsan I see (and anyway I didn't downvote, especially because you provide a good starting point), I have to admit my comment is more _directed_ to OP than to you

Comment: I blv this question should get on hold

Comment: According to SO rules

Comment: @user I really suggest you not to ask your homework or interview questions on SO since your question will get downvoted badly

Comment: First think of an algorithm and if you encountered a problem come and ask on SO

Comment: @Adriano forgive me if I were rude

Comment: @Ehsan you were not!

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible with standard C functions, as they all wait for an end of line/file indicator before returning. The user would have to press enter after every letter they type.

Also, there is no way with standard C to relocate the position in the console where you will be writing the warning.

Since this is a beginner programming course, it would seem that your teacher is simply looking for a non-standard console function. If your teacher is a dinosaur of some sort, the solution is to use the functions from `conio.h`. Otherwise if your teacher is decent, the solution is to use Ncurses or the Windows API console functions, or a similar modern platform-dependant solution.

Comment: conio.h include this functions: Conio.h functions
clrscr
delline
getch
getche
gotoxy
kbhit
wherex
wherey
textcolor
textbackground   How these gonna help me?

Comment: No only some of them

Comment: since some of them only work on 16 bit systems like DOS

Comment: @user2719403 you already know what to use then...what's the problem with them?

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea:

1. Use a text editor that automatically flushes data at regular intervals.
2. This is a bad idea but you may have to use a infinite loop for checking all data till `EOF` (End Of File) at regular intervals.(you may use `getchar()`)

Still it mostly depends on how a OS handles a file `rwx`

Comment: getchar is a disaster for this exercise

Comment: coz as you enter a character you should press Return

Comment: flush also isn't good

Comment: @Ehsan there is no need to press Return for getchar() it simply gets char from buffer and i was talking about text editor auto save function not c flush() function.