# ofstream:- no output on the text file though the file is getting created

Tags: c++, string, c++14, fstream, ofstream

```
    void megaadmin()
    {
        system("cls");
        cout<<"this console is only for registering new admins";
        cout<<"please enter the required username";
        string temporary_string;
        cin>>temporary_string;
        ofstream f("admin_details.txt",ios::out|ios::app);
        f<<temporary_string;
        cout<<"please enter the password";
        cin>>temporary_string;
        f<<temporary_string;
        cout<<"would u like to enter more usernames and passwords if yes enter 1 eles 2";
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        if(n==1)
            megaadmin();
        else
            exit(0);
    }
```

admin_details.txt is getting created but the information that is the username and password that i entering is not getting stored in that particular text file

Comment: *When* and *how* do you check the contents of the file? Perhaps you should `flush` the buffers before checking?

Comment: Also (but unrelated to your problem), I suggest you use *loops* instead of recursion in the code you show.

Comment: Also unrelated: there's no point in specifying `ios::out` on an `ofstream`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i am new to c++ how would i flush in this code?

Comment: @varunkrishna use `ostream::flush()`. For example, `f.flush()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After each `cin >> temporary_string;` I would add `cout << temporary_string` **for debugging only** to make sure that the string is read successfully.

If it is, then there is no output since your stream is probably not flushed.
Just call `f.flush()` and you should see the content.

BTW, when you close the program, the stream will be flushed as well during destruction, so you will see the content as well.

Comment: i dont exactly understand flush but i did flush still it is not working but i recently made another code with some ofstream that is working perfectly fine i dont know why this one is not working

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105650/how-does-stdflush-work) out to see what is flushing