# How to create a txt file that writes in it while I type (KeyLogger)

Tags: c++

I made a keylogger and it works great. The only problem that I have is it outputs the keylogger to the txt file just after I close the console. I'd to write in the txt file while I use the keylogger and not that I'd output the keylogger just after I close the console. I am now using fstream to write the file. This is what I am doing right now to print the keylogger the the txt file

```
ofstream writeFile;
writeFile.open("test.txt"); // opening file
writeFile << key;
```

Comment: You probably just need to flush the stream. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush

Comment: As @drescherjm suggested, do  `writeFile << key << std::flush;`

Comment: Also I believe the question should not mention keylogger at all. The problem seems to about writing a file and has nothing at all to do with a keylogger in whatever OS you are using.

Comment: @drescherjm You are right. Sorry. Thank you for the answer

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does std::flush work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105650/how-does-stdflush-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `flush` a buffered stream in order to guarantee saving your output before a `close`:

```
writeFile << key << std::flush;
```

Your other option is to unbuffer the stream:

```
ofstream writeFile;
writeFile.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(0, 0); // unbuffer stream
writeFile.open("test.txt"); // open file
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know also why is "\b" dosen't work in the file? It does "" insted of deleting the text

Comment: Because `'\b'` is part of the `char` stream, your terminal handler performs the magic to move the cursor backwards and overwrite the previous `char`.

Comment: So there is no way deleting char?

Comment: Deleting isn't normally possible. You can overwrite though. Just step the `ofstream` pointer back and write a new value. Note: `\b` is not an instruction, it's just another value to add to the stream - and you can truncate files - but not streams, if that's needed.

Comment: @TedLyngmo How can I pointer it back and write a new value?

Comment: @Eathat If it's a file stream, just use [seekp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/seekp) when writing. or `seekg` for reading (on a `istream` type). That being said, if you are doing a keylogger, you want even backspaces and timings logged. :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo got it. Thanks. What do you mean "if you are doing a keylogger, you want even backspaces and timings logged."

Comment: A keylogger worth the name lets you investigate what the user actually did - and pauses and backspaces tells you a lot. It also helps identifying who actually wrote the stuff afterwards. We all have unique patterns. So, each keystroke should be logged with timing if this is going to be used in a forensic analysis etc.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I see, for somereason my seekp does not work this is what I did I posted it above as updated

Comment: Sounds like a new question. It's hard to read in this comment format.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I posted it in my qustion for some reason I need the approve of the guy who posted the answer.

Comment: Seams reasonable, since you are changing a question with an accepted answer. I think you should create a new question.

Comment: @TedLyngmo My falut There. I changed my qustion.

Comment: Make a new question instead. The original question has an answer. Don't add to it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo You are right. I will. What do you think the title should be? I can't think of a good one to be honest.....

Comment: Revert the latest edit of this question so that others with similar questions may benefit from reading it later. Then, take the parts you now need clarifying to the new question into a new mininal example.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I did, I know but I still can't think of a good title. The best title I have is "why seekp Isn't working in my code". Which is a bad title.

Comment: @Eathat  I'm afraid that's a part of programming too :-) Describing your problem. Deal with what you have now for awhile and then, if you don't make it work, pose another question. It'll be easy to formulate then I think.

Comment: @TedLyngmo you are right. I'll ask it tommorow anyway. It's late or should I say morning. Good night/morning I guess.

Comment: @Eathat Cheers!